What parameters give unlinear torque model of induction motor?
I want to realize factors which give nonlinear model of torque toward speed with power consumption in induction motor.
I tried find math model induction motor. But usually, I had same charts:

As we can see, its stuff model. Because we have max torque in start, and oscillation changing torque in next time. As well, models not have catching with electric current in stators. All in all, i cant get some benefits from same models.
I realized, that with right start, squirrel cage will be same with short circuit transformer. E=dФ/dt. Rotor speed in start = 0. Magnet field in rotor will be rotated 50/60 times per second. But big power not give high magnet torque, because rotor limited by hysteresis and permeability of electric steel. And as result, we get high current and limited magnet flow.
But! Why that magnet flow in rotor will be lower than magnet flow in ~sync frequency, when magnet filed rotate 2-4 time per second?
If watch to picture with  torque/speed with difference frequency, we find that negatives effects of right starts give high frequency in rotor. Rotor cant catch circuit magnet field of stator. But which factor influence for that? Hysteresis, which give delay on magnet filed of rotor? Skin-effect for magnets conductor in rotor? Or maybe other factors give nonlinear characteristics of induction motor?


Alex F - Hi, Where did those images come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) please [edit] the question & add its name & link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. a book), there is more detail in that site rule. Always reference to the best of your ability. TY (Please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules.)

@DavideAndrea your amendment has an error where you replaced "unlinear" with "linear". The OP clearly means "non-linear" and also, you haven't been consistent with this change i.e. the title still says "unlinear" and so does the body just above the first picture. So, I'm rolling this back to how it was.

@DavideAndrea Thank you!

@Andy aka - I clearly remember replacing "unlinear" with "non-linear" (not with "linear"). But I am OK with your reversal. I was just trying to help.

@DavideAndrea if you check the edit history it's clear that your amendments didn't do this.

@Andy aka Does the edit history show the history of the titles? I don't see it. I do remember doing so in the title. But, again, I am OK with your reversal.
